# why my data passed by binding stay undefined?

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding

I have a set of data in JSON and I tried to pass them one by one in a ngfor, to display the data in another component but when I do so I have an error X is undefined.
first component

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

const data= [{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5ef3493e7322c93b9cc6fdf7"
  },
  "name": "TP python 1",
  "coefTP": 0,
  "date": {
    "$date": "2020-01-23T00:00:00.441Z"
  }
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5ef354dd7322c93b9cc6fdfa"
  },
  "name": "TP python 2",
  "coefTP": 1,
  "date": {
    "$date": "2020-01-23T00:00:00.441Z"
  }
}];

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-tps',
  templateUrl: './my-tps.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-tps.component.css']
})
export class MyTPsComponent implements OnInit {
  tpList : any[] = data;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

}
```

```html
<h1 class="text-center display-1">My TPs</h1>
<hr class="w-25">
<div class="bg-light ml-5">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <app-tp-item *ngFor="let tp of tpList" [sendtp]="tp" class="col-md-6 col-lg-3 col-xs-8">
        </app-tp-item>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

second component

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, retry } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tp-item',
  templateUrl: './tp-item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tp-item.component.css']
})
export class TpItemComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() sendtp: JSON;
  public readonly nom:string;
  public readonly date:string;
  public readonly coeff:number;
  public readonly id:string;

  constructor() {
    this.nom=this.sendtp['name'];
    this.date=this.sendtp['date'];
    this.coeff=this.sendtp['coefTP'];
    this.id=this.sendtp['_id'];
  }
}
```

```html
the html part only shows:
    this.nom;
    this.date;
    this.coeff;
    this.id=this;
```

the error says that in the second component

@Input() sendtp: JSON; //<-- this is undefined

I'd like to know why it stay undefined, could you help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Constructor` works when instance of a component is created (like other programming languages).

`ngOnInit` works when the data of component has been bound.

Moreover, you are trying to reach them on `constructor`, so it must be undefined because the data (or props) are not bound yet.

To solve the issue you need to reach them at `ngOnInit` lifecycle

```
export class TpItemComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() sendtp: JSON;
  public nom:string;
  public date:string;
  public coeff:number;
  public id:string;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.nom=this.sendtp['name'];
    this.date=this.sendtp['date'];
    this.coeff=this.sendtp['coefTP'];
    this.id=this.sendtp['_id'];
  }
}
```

Check this out for more information about [Angular Lifecycle](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)

Answer (score 2):

You assigned the value in constructor which is caused to the undefined. In Angular Life cycle, Initially constructor will be called. So better to assign it in ngOnInit().

Added working stackblitz [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/child-component-an9fir)